# InitilizeExt() for encoder is failing for openH264

Tags: openh264

I am implementing the openH264 in my solution. I am facing issue with the calls to Initialize() [for encoder with basic parameter] and InitializeExt() [for encoder with extension parameter]. It is always returning 1(cmInitParaError). I verified the samples provided in the link https://github.com/cisco/openh264/wiki/UsageExampleForEncoder. But still its failing.

Is there any specific things need to be set?

Sample code is given below;

```
SEncParamExt param;
encoder->GetDefaultParams(&param);
int rv = encoder->InitializeExt(&param);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the console sample, welsenc.cpp, in codec\console\enc\src.
It works for me.